# Displaying records from EXT:news in specific language

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to display a news record in a different language to the default language where no record in the default language exists.

The multilanguage configuration is

```
 config {
    sys_language_mode = strict
    sys_language_overlay = 0
 }
```

The Plugin on the page is set to 'All languages'.

News only existing in the default language are suppressed as expected, but news only available in another language are not appended to the list.

(EXT:news version is 2.2.1, TYPO3 Version is 4.7.14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the persistence layer of Extbase. The only workaround known to me is to create a news record in the default language, hide it in the default language and make a translation of the news. Then the news record is displayed only in the translated version.

**Update TYPO3 6.2:**

As of TYPO3 6.2.4 (see https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/commit/c78a2e051a5c163a54150013ceb96fe2542a8c11), the Extbase query parser work properly with localized versions of records without a default language version. The workaround is not needed anymore.