# EXT:news only in additional language – images missing in frontend

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-7.6.x

Similar to [Displaying records from EXT:news in specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449263/displaying-records-from-extnews-in-specific-language) I have a two-language site news and the settings:

```
sys_language_mode = strict
sys_language_overlay = 0
```

In the second language (en), the ext:news plugin should display news that have been regularly translated, but also english "orphans" that don't exist in the main language (de).

While this works for text, the **images** aren't displayed in the frontend.

They *do* appear in the backend, but as there is no original in the main language, I don't get the localisation buttons for the media files.

How can images be displayed for english "orphan" news?

Comment: try with config.sys_language_overlay = 1 and config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback

Comment: Interesting! This works for the list page, but not for the detail. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try EXT:    repair_translation

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This seems to be an auto comment triggered by the shortness of the answer. To me, the the answer was very helpful, it's backward compatible and seems to work! I wouldn't know any information that could be added for users that can relate to the question itself.

Comment: Hey, nice to hear that i could help. I like breaking down Infomation to his essence :)